# WordPress function for 1 to for many

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I have this function:

```
add_filter( 'prdctfltr_show_filter', 'my_hide_filter_on_category_function_jkbg4iu3b' );

function my_hide_filter_on_category_function_jkbg4iu3b() {
 if ( is_product_category( 'cheese' ) ) {
  return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```

Is any possibility to use ONE function and ONE filter but for MANY WooC Product Categories - not only for "cheese" but also for "sausages, wine, chocolate, etc" at ONE function and ONE filter?

Something like:

```
   or: if ( is_product_category( 'cheese' or "ham" ) ) {
   or: if ( is_product_category( 'cheese' || "ham" ) ) {
   or: if ( is_product_category( array => 'cheese, ham" ) ) {
```

?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use it like:

```
if ( is_product_category('cheese', 'fruit', 'meat') )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it NOT work. This is the problem - this function for some reason works only with 1 attribute. :( Here it's original info: https://help.xforwoocommerce.com/product-filter/optimizing-filtering-experience/how-to-hide-filters-on-categories/ - maybe developers just don't do something what needs to use this function with many categories names?? :(